# CSS, express and bootstrap : layout in the page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I would like to have this layout : [What I would like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8IiF.png)
The "Resultat" label should be placed under the image.

Unfortunately, what I get is : [What I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evc3N.png)
You can see that the "Résultat" label is not well situated.

Here is my CSS :

```
body  {
  background-color: #A6A4AA !important;
}

.mainContainer {
  background-color: #A6A4AA
}

.label-selected, .label-unselected, .label-result, .result-field, .label-univers, .label-target {
  border: solid medium #2C3756;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #E6F0BB;
  color: #405E01;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}


.label-target, .label-result, .result-field {
  margin-top: 2px;
  font-size: 0.875em;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: #2C3756;
  text-align: left;
  color : #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.label-target  {
  border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
}

.label-result, .result-field {
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.result-field {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #2C3756;
  border-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.targetImage {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border: solid medium #2C3756;
    border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
    background-color: #A6A4AA;
    position: relative;
}


#targetCol {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;

}


.ajustement {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.label-result, .result-field {
  float: none !important;
}
```

And here is my express code :

```
<div class="row">    <!-- Row : target            -->
  <div class= "col-xs-12" id="targetCol">
    <img id="target" class="targetImage"></img>
    <div id="ajustement" class="ajustement"></div>
    <div id="impact" class="impact"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">    <!-- Row : result            -->
  <div class= "col-xs-3 short-div">
    <p class="label-result">R&eacute;sultats</p>
  </div>
  <div class= "col-xs-9 short-div">
    <p class="result-field" id="resultField">...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone explain to me what's going on ?

Thank by advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think because you are using `position: relative` for displaying your image. It sets itself independent from the other div. Try using a div for you image and do not use **position** instead of that use `width:100%;height:xyz px;`. Avoid using position set it by giving width or using bootstrap column.

Comment: Thank you @Ashish sah, it helped a lot. I removed the "position:absolute" for the column (#targetCol, and it worked out.